# Sending data in table format in email context bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a table of data which I want to send in an email. The data is stored in TestOutput2.csv in table format as:

```
354508| 80| Apr 29 2013 12:00AM
453630| 84| Oct 24 2013 12:00AM
```

I use

```
echo `cat TestOutput.csv` | mailx -s "Trades matured , Trade_Nmbr, Hedge_Ref, Maturity_Date" email@email.com
```

The result is an email with the context:

```
354508| 80| Apr 29 2013 12:00AM| | 453630| 84| Oct 24 2013 12:00AM
```

So basically I want it in table format, any suggestions?

Comment: Managed to solve it by putting the cat at a new line:
echo "TradeNumber HedgeReference MaturityDate 
`cat TestOutput`" | mailx -s "Trades maturing today, Trade_Nmbr, Hedge_Ref, Maturity_Date" email@email.com

Comment: Input redirection is the correct thing to do here. However, if the criterion were to make minimum changes to your code, all you missed were a pair of quotes: `echo "\`cat TestOutput.csv\`" | mailx .....`. Adding this comment only for informing you what you missed. The ideal way is by using redirection as given in vijay's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command instead:

```
mailx -s "some subject" email@email.com < inputfile.csv
```

So your command would be:

```
mailx -s "Trades matured , Trade_Nmbr, Hedge_Ref, Maturity_Date" email@email.com < TestOutput.csv
```

Comment: Better than my because you use input redirection